# How to get distance between 2 CPoint?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have 2 CPoint on Screen follow:

```
CPoint cp1 ;x-y (314;448)
CPoint cp2 ;x-y (802;448)
```

I tried this but got skewed results

`pixels = (cp2.x-cp1.x)*96/72`

How to get distance between these point in pixel?

Comment: sqrt((x1-x2)²+( y1-y2)²)

Comment: Hi @RolandStarke, Thank you . I was just not sure at the numbers 96 & 72, but now you have clarified for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

with this formula and define Point Type easily done :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
int main()
{
    point p1,p2;
    p1.x=2;
    p1.y=36;
    p2.x=6;
    p2.y=33;
    //=========
    int x1= p1.x -p2.x;
    x1 = abs(x1);
    x1 = x1*x1;
    
    int y1 = p1.y-p2.y;
    y1 = abs(y1);
    y1 = y1*y1;
    
    int res = sqrt(x1+y1);
    cout<<"Distance = "<<res<<endl;
    
    
}
```